# Synchronise sql server data between mobile device and laptop

Tags: .net, mobile, sql-server-ce, synchronization

My second question on mobile platform applications.

We are doing an application for a mobile computer MC2100 and using SQL CE as the database. Now that the application is done and I've data in my SQL CE Database, I'm looking for ways to sync (2 way sync) this data with a SQL Express running on a tablet pc.

I can choose how to do the sync, i.e. all viable options can be looked at.

1.Can I for instance connect **directly** to the CE DB in the device from .Net code running on the tablet, i.e. put in a path in the connection string that takes me directly to the CE DB (which I doubt) but if possible is what I'm looking for.

2.Further, due to the nature of the updates involved,  **copying** over the CE DB to the tablet, followed by a two way updation and a final copy back to the mobile device is not the desired route, and to be honest I do not know how to do that either!

3.Is there a 3rd party utility that I could use, this could help - http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortCommand.html, but I'm not able to follow it for the most part. Has anyone used this?

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Unfortunately, this is not an option. SQL CE does not support remote connections.

2 - I know you say it's not desired, but this is exactly the route I took for a very similar task involving a SQL CE database on a Windows Mobile 6.5 device, syncing to a SQL Express database on a server.

The process involved copying the database from the device to the server using RAPI, then using the Sync Framework to sync the CE database with the SQL database, then using RAPI again to copy the database back to the device.

Although it sounds like a convoluted process, it actually works quite nicely, and I think it is probably your best option.

3 - I can't really help you here, but based on that web page, it appears that the utility is only for copying entire databases, not for performing a 2 way sync.

Comment: Thanks for your input, if the above walkthrough and the Primeworks site proves too much I'll have to go the copy route, will update next week.

Comment: This worked for me, and as you said sounded complicated, but was relatively simple.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this walkthrough as well: Walkthrough: [Creating an Occasionally Connected Smart Device Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488004.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look through this and will report back next week if this works for me.

Comment: I decided to go the Copy route - thanks for your suggestion though.